# Credentials Privacy for Python Project on GitHub

Tags: python, mysql

I am using my database username and passowrd to connect to a database while connecting to my database through python. Evrything works fine but I want to put this project to github and yet make sure I dont compromise the privacy of my credentials. Can anyone help?

I am hesitant to upload anything with my passoword in there but I want it to work for anyone who copies the code and runs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options

Store your database credentials as environment variables on your local machine and access them in your Python code. This way, you won't be hardcoding the credentials in your code, and others can set up their environment variables to run the code.

---

Create a separate configuration file (e.g., config.ini or config.py) where you can store your database credentials. Add this file to your .gitignore file to ensure it's not pushed to GitHub. Others can create their own configuration file with their credentials when they clone your project.

```
# config.py
DB_USERNAME = 'your_database_username'
DB_PASSWORD = 'your_database_password'
```

Then in your main Python code:

```
# main.py
from config import DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD
# ... rest of the code ...

# Use DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD in your database connection code
```

Comment: But adding config files to .gitignore would mean that it would not be uploaded to github; hence, the only way is for others to set up their environment variables. Is there any other way such as Firebase or other authenticators so that the user can access data without worrying about the credentials

Comment: @Jagggy Jazz I originally thought everyone can have their own version of the code and their own database? Or do you want to distribute the project with your database and allow others to interact with it without them knowing the credentials ?

Comment: yes, I would like it to be accessible to everyone without them knowing the credentials.

Comment: @JagggyJazz what operations are they allowed to do on the database? You can create a user just to limit them to read-only. I don't see the point of masking the credentials if they will have a connection to the database and be able to execute any query they want.

Comment: read-only access is fine enough